# Handling window modal pop up in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am trying to follow twitter handle of lambdatest website https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-playground/window-popup-modal-demo the Modal pop is launched successfully but thereafter I am unable to proceed further this is my code `I have tried using driver.switch.to.iframe still same issue also switch to alert is not working here this a a modal popup but in the dic the modal pop up element is not appearing.

```
package lambdatest;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;`

public class Lambdatestplayground {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // to navigate to the website
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Path to chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.get("https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-playground/window-popup-modal-demo");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(7));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"__next\"]/section[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a")).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> 1- To dismiss the Popup use the below code:

Webdriver wait;
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

        // Storing the alert in variable
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

        alert.dismiss();

> 2- To Accept the popup use the below code:
Webdriver wait;
Alert alrt = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

        // Sending the data into the alert popup
        alrt.sendKeys(input);

        // press the OK button
        alrt.accept();
```

Comment: I already know how to dismiss it but I want to handle this by clicking on follow button  inside the Twitter pop up,and thanks for the answer